# Why is 0x1 interpreted as less than 0xC0000000?

Tags: c, binary, integer, hex, bit-manipulation

I'm learning about binary representation of integers and tried to write a function that returns an `int` multiplied by 2 using saturation. The thought process is if the value overflows positively the function returns `INT_MAX`, and conversely if it overflows negatively it returns `INT_MIN`. In all other cases the binary value is left shifted by 1.

What I'm wondering is why I have to cast the value `0xC0000000` as an `int` in order to get my function to work correctly when I pass the argument `x = 1`.

Here is my function:

```
int timestwo (int x){
    if(x >= 0x40000000) // INT_MAX/2 + 1
        return 0x7fffffff; // INT_MAX
    else if(x < (int) 0xC0000000) // INT_MIN/2
        return 0x80000000; // INT_MIN
    else
        return x << 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming twos-complement 32-bit `int`, `return x << 1;` results in undefined behavior if `x <= ( int ) 0x80000000` and `x >= ( int ) 0xC0000000`.

Comment: So, why do you assume you know the actual values for `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`?  And worse, if you know there are such constants, why don't you use them?  The constants are there to avoid architecture dependencies, that are commonly solved by comparing values of the same type.

Comment: @LuisColorado As said in the post, it is a learning exercise. I determined INT_MAX and INT_MIN for a specific architecture relevant to the exercise to better learn about bit-wise representation. I would have gained nothing by just plopping in the constants.

Comment: @qq4, you don't say in the exercise (and neither you do in your comment above) the reasons to use the values, instead of the constants.  How have you determined that the constants will don't work and your values do?  I'm afraid you are not telling something essential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hexadecimal (and octal) literals in C are typed using the smallest promoted (=`int` or a higher ranking type) type, signed or unsigned, that can accommodate the value.
This differs from decimal literals, which stay within signed types if they don't have the `u`/`U` suffix, or within unsigned types otherwise ([6.4.4.1p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5)):

[image: integer-literal types]

This makes `0xC0000000` on a system with 32-bit integers unsigned and comparing (or otherwise pairing by means of an operator) an unsigned with a signed of the same rank forces the signed to become unsigned ([6.3.1.8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)), so without the `(int)` cast you get an implicit `(unsigned int)x < (unsigned int) 0xC0000000`.

Answer (score 2):

The value specified by the constant `0xC0000000` will not fit in an `int` (assuming 32 bit), but it does fit in an `unsigned int`, so the type of this constant is `unsigned int`.  This unsigned value is larger than 1 so the comparison evaluates to false.

The result of the cast to `int` is actually implementation defined, although on a two's complement system this will typically result in what you would expect.